# simple html dom: how get a tag without certain attribute

Tags: php, parsing, css-selectors, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I want to get the tags with "class" attribute equal to "someclass" but only those tags that hasn't defined the attribute "id".

**I tried** the following (based on this answer) but didn't work:

```
$html->find('.someclass[id!=*]');
```

**Note:**

I'm using [Simple HTML DOM class](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) and in the basic documentation that they give, I didn't find what I need.

Comment: For CSS3 selectors, try http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Simple HTML DOM class](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) does not support [CSS3 pseudo classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes) which is required for negative attribute matching.

It is simple to work around the limitation without much trouble.

```
$nodes = array_filter($html->find('.something'), function($node){return empty($node->id);});
```

Comment: I had just posted a similar question but in my code i'm getting all elements with a class which do not have a specific ID set. Would you mind showing what the return would be if I needed to check id !=some_id Thanks

Comment: `$nodes = array_filter($html->find('.something'), function($node){return (!empty($node->id) && $node->id != 'some_id');});`

Comment: Thanks, I saw you suggested phpquery which accepts css3 selectors. Is there any performance difference between this and simple html dom?

Answer (score 6):

From the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), under the [How to find HTML elements?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find), we can read:

> [!attribute]   Matches elements that **don't have** the specified attribute.

**Your code would become:**

```
$html->find('.someclass[!id]');
```

This will match elements with a class `someClass` that do not have an `id` attribute.

---

My original answer was based on the selection of elements just like we would with jQuery since the Simple HTML DOM Parser claims to support them on their [main page](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) where we can read:

> Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.

<sup>My sincere apologies to those who were offended by my original answer and expressed their displeasure in the comments!</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but that operator doesn't works for PHP code using Simple HTML DOM class (see link of it in my post).

Comment: yes, that is what i do, but I'm not sure if there isn't another solution, thanks, +1 for you

Comment: I down voted because, even though you are technically correct, the question has nothing to do with jquery.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas Sorry about that, I've updated the answer with a solution from the documentation.

Comment: @h0tw1r3 While you may be correct that it is not related with jQuery, I use it as such for years now, and without any problems. Their principle is to select elements with CSS selectors just like jQuery does. Anyways, I've updated the answer with a solution to the OP's problem that is also documented on the Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual.

Comment: Worked great! Simple and effective. +1